# AutoComplete work fine in development server but not in production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete

I had an asp.net page in C# with the autocomplete textbox field (using AutoCompleteExtender).

The list displayed correctly (in multiple line dropdownlist) in my development server. But it's displayed all the data in single line when deployed to production server.

My development server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. My production server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter using Windows Azure in cloud.

Any idea what is causing that?

Comment: Are all the CSS in the production server up to date and are they loaded correctly?

Comment: Supposed to. Cause I copied all files from the development server over to my production server. Will there be any problem by doing this way? I will double check on that.